# Covert Time Returned by Facebook Graph API to readable Time Format

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, time

I m getting Time data in this format in an JSON Object.

```
 "created_time": "2012-04-01T15:02:52+0000"
```

I need to convert this format to some readable time format like

```
 3:02 PST 1 April, 2012
```

So the users understand it. I m using Jquery for handling this data.
I tried doing it but I m not understanding which time format it is !

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?

Comment: I simply tried converting it simply by slicing the data and doing it manually ! But thats not a very efficient method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to do something like this, which should actually be human readable:

```
var date = new Date("2012-04-01T15:02:52+0000")
console.log(date); //Sun Apr 01 2012 17:02:52 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Summer Time)
```

Using the Date object, you are able to convert it further, should you want.

See http://www.elated.com/articles/working-with-dates/ for some nice examples, like:

```
date.toDateString(); //Sun Apr 01 2012​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Comment: Sun Apr 01 2012 20:32:52 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want [Timeago](http://timeago.yarp.com/) plugin !